# SQL Counting the Count Results

Tags: sql

I'm trying to generate reports from sales that I want to show in data studio. I have column email, order_number and total_price and I'm trying to identify the following using sql query:

1. Number of repeating and new customer (counting number of orders, if order > 1 then repeating, else new)
2. Number of orders from repeating and new customers

```
    Date     | email             | Order_number | Total Price 
---------------------------------------------------------------
    101019   | email1@email.com  | 1111         | 100         
    101019   | email2@email.com  | 1112         | 200        
    111019   | email3@email.com  | 1113         | 130         
    111019   | email1@email.com  | 1111         | 100
```

What I did is only to count the number of orders each email

```
SELECT email, count(email) as order_count, date FROM orders GROUP BY 
email
```

This is  sample report that I want to show

```
    Repeating Customer | New Customer  
        1              |       2


    Orders from Repeating Cust. | Orders from New Customer
          2                     |    2


    Total Price Repeating Cust. | Total Price New Custo.
          200                   |      330
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try Case and Sub query:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t.Cust_cnt=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS New_Cust,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.Cust_cnt>1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Repeat_Cust,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.Cust_cnt=1 THEN t.Total_Order ELSE 0 END) AS New_Cust_Order,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.Cust_cnt>1 THEN t.Total_Order ELSE 0 END) AS Repeat_Cust_Order,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.Cust_cnt=1 THEN t.Total_Price ELSE 0 END) AS New_Cust_Order_Total_Price,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.Cust_cnt>1 THEN t.Total_Price ELSE 0 END) AS Repeat_Cust_OrderTotal_Price,
       t.Last_Order_Date
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(Email) AS Cust_cnt,SUM(O_Price) AS Total_Price,COUNT(O_Number) AS Total_Order, MAX(O_Date) AS Last_Order_Date, Email  FROM Orders Group by Email) AS t;
```

Comment: How can I include the date?

Comment: U can take `max` or `min` date as I edited in answer

Comment: however as per your post you can also  used `order no` instead `email`

Answer (score 0):

Use two separate queries, one for repeating and one for new customers, then simply join them to create your report.

**REPEATING CUSTOMERS**

```
SELECT email, COUNT(email), SUM(TotalPrice) as order_count FROM orders GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(email) > 1
```

**NEW CUSTOMERS**

```
SELECT email, SUM(TotalPrice) as order_count FROM orders GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(email) = 1
```

If you're using a front-end technology to display these results, you can compile these results into horizontal orientation (repeating and new customers in two columns instead of two rows) on the front-end too. If you want to do this in pure SQL, just CROSS JOIN the two queries to get your output.

Comment: It may give error for _GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'orders.date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause_

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper: ah yes, removed them, since output doesn't need them anyway.